# dir=auto attribute is not working when applied to div tag

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have applied the `dir=auto` attribute to a `<div>` element in order to get text alignment based on the input language.
But if any `<p> tag` is present inside the `<div>` then the `dir=auto` attribute is not working for the `<p>` tag. Again I have to apply the `dir` attribute to `p` tag also.

Is there any behavior difference when both `div` and `p` tags are present?.

```
<div id="EditBox" dir=auto contenteditable="true" style="margin: 5px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;">
<p style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;"><br></p>
</div>
```

I am testing this in the android emulator.

Can we apply the `dir` attribute to the body element, so that it will take care of text alignment based on input language?

Comment: This applies more broadly than just in Android.

Answer (score 6):

The attribute [`dir=auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-dir-attribute) (an HTML5 novelty with limited support) sets the directionality of the element according to the first characters with strong directionality. It does not try to analyze the language of the text at all.

The only way to make an element’s directionality depend on its own content in this sense is to set the `dir` attribute to the value `auto` on the element itself. You cannot make this attribute inherited.

But you can use JavaScript to traverse an element and set the `dir` property to `"auto"` for the desired descendants.

Comment: > according to the first characters with strong directionality ||

Jukka, thank you very much for this note, it saved my day!